# Load content from a dir with .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, configuration

Suppose we have `domain.com`, and `test.domain.com` as a sub-domain.>
Apache's Document Root is `/var/www`.

The home folder of test.domain.com is located in `/home/user/domain.com/test`, by default from the hoster.

I want to load content from the dir `/usr/local/www/domain.com/test`.

I am trying (unsucceful) to  this with .htaccess file. Is that possible?

Can I load the content from another directory folder?
 I am on shared hosting and I don't have access to the configuration files of Apache.

Comment: Yes, you can load the content from another directory, but maybe a further description of what you want will be helpful. It's not clear enough, at least for me.

Comment: You can't do this with htaccess, as apache prevents access to files outside of the document-root (in your case `/var/www/domain.com/test`). You have to edit your `<virtualhost>` and change `DocumentRoot`

Comment: Thank you both! I found a solution to my problem, bypassing the usage of .htaccess file. :) Post updated!